# Copy activity - sink stored procedure parameter value ignored

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

After adding a `copy activity`, and specifying a stored procedure to use - I want to add a stored procedure parameter:

[image]

Running the activity, I get an error saying that there is no value specified for the stored procedure parameter `projectId`.

Looking at the generated JSON code for the `copy activity`, I can indeed see that there is no value set for the parameter:

```
"sink": {
    "type": "SqlSink",
    "writeBatchSize": 10000,
    "sqlWriterStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[CreateAllocation]",
    "sqlWriterTableType": "AllocationType",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "projectId": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
},
"enableStaging": false,
"cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
```

Setting the value of the parameter by clicking the `Advanced` tab on the `copy activity`, and pasting the following JSON makes it work:

```
"sink": {
    "type": "SqlSink",
    "writeBatchSize": 10000,
    "sqlWriterStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[CreateAllocation]",
    "sqlWriterTableType": "AllocationType",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "projectId": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "200"
        }
    }
},
"enableStaging": false,
"cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
```

I've also tried to connect the data factory to git, and making a commit that sets the value of the stored procedure parameter - but no luck. As soon as the copy activity has loaded, it seems like it strips out the value set for the parameter.

How come that I can't set the value of the stored procedure parameter, without using the `Advanced` tab to override the activity template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has already been fixed. With the lasted UI, you won't hit this issue.